# why multiple columns are shown as one vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in data from a URL however when I do run the following code:

```
x <- read.csv(url(myUrl), sep = '\t', head = FALSE)
print(x)
```

I get this

```
                         V1      V2
1   18.0   8   30.7   130.0   hello
2   32.0   6   23.5   121.5   bye
```

and I want this

```
      V1    V2     V3      V4      V5 
1   18.0   8.0   30.7   130.0   hello
2   32.0   6.0   23.5   121.5   bye
```

for some reason it is reading it as 2 columns instead of 5

**Edit 1**

Here is a snippet of the data file from the url:

[image]

**Edit 2**
Here is the url: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data

Comment: can you show the `myUrl`, so that it can be tested

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\t`, may be, use use `' '` or don't specify the delimiter

```
x <- read.table(url(myUrl), header = FALSE)
```

---

based on the url updated in the OP's post

```
x <- read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data", header = FALSE)
str(x)
#'data.frame':  398 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ V1: num  18 15 18 16 17 15 14 14 14 15 ...
# $ V2: int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
# $ V3: num  307 350 318 304 302 429 454 440 455 390 ...
# $ V4: chr  "130.0" "165.0" "150.0" "150.0" ...
# $ V5: num  3504 3693 3436 3433 3449 ...
# $ V6: num  12 11.5 11 12 10.5 10 9 8.5 10 8.5 ...
# $ V7: int  70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
# $ V8: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ V9: chr  "chevrolet chevelle malibu" "buick skylark 320" "plymouth satellite" "amc rebel sst" ...
```

Comment: @tkxgoogle what is the output you are getting.  Generally, it should work.  As the input data is not showed, it is unclear

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the first three lines of your csv data?